# PowerShell: How to select one of multiple Active Directories in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have multiple Azure subscriptions with the same tenant, each one of them has their own Active Directory. When switching subscriptions, I still read/write to the AD of my default subscription. How can I access the other directories with PowerShell cmdlets?

Get-AzSubscription gives me this:

```
Name             Id                                   TenantId                             State
----             --                                   --------                             -----
Subscription 01  10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 abc00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000abc Enabled
Subscription 02  20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002 abc00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000abc Enabled
Subscription 03  30000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003 abc00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000abc Enabled
```

Now I can switch between these like this

```
#> Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"
#> Get-AzContext

Name             Account                 SubscriptionName  Environment  TenantId
----             -------                 ----------------  -----------  --------
Subscription 02  myaccount@mydomain.com  Subscription 02   AzureCloud   abc00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000abc 

#> Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "30000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003"
#> Get-AzContext

Name             Account                 SubscriptionName  Environment  TenantId
----             -------                 ----------------  -----------  --------
Subscription 03  myaccount@mydomain.com  Subscription 03   AzureCloud   abc00000-0000-0000-0000-000000000abc
```

When using Get-AzADUser to retrieve information about a user in these subscriptions' Active Directories, it does not work - it always communicates with the AD of Subscription 01. I also tried to run Select-AzContext instead of Set-AzContext with the same result.

The ADs have completely different IDs, like 0847BCD0-0000-0000-0000-00000039C76F when looking them up in Azure portal. But could not figure out where to use them.

Could anyone please explain what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** Just to illustrate this further, when executing Get-AzADUser I get the same result set no matter what subscription I have selected with Set-AzContext. There are no error messages whatsoever but I'd expect to get the users from the AD of the subscription I have selected.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: When using Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName user@subscription2.com I don't get any error message, I just don't get any user information back, I can only retrieve users from subscription 01. When adding a new user I get "New-AzADUser: The domain portion of the userPrincipalName property is invalid. You must use one of the verified domain names in your organization." This is due to the fact that the different subscriptions use different domains - and I would like to add user@subscription2.com to subscription 2, but PowerShell will still try to add it in subscription 01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your Azure tenant you have multiple AAD tenants.  The TenantId property you've listed is the id for your Azure tenant.  The AAD tenant ids you can see in the portal can also be retrieved using PowerShell by running `Get-AzTenant`.  To connect to one of these AAD tenants so that you can run commands such as `Get-AzADUser` add the -Tenant parameter when using `Login-AzAccount`, eg:

```
Login-AzAccount -Tenant 0847BCD0-0000-0000-0000-00000039C76F
```

When you run `Get-AzADUser` you should now get the users for that AAD tenant rather than your default AAD tenant.

Comment: Thanks, that was super helpful - Microsoft's nomenclature is quite confusing. However, would there be an option to actually switch between AAD tenants when logged in? Without going through the login procedure again?

Comment: `Set-AzContext` has a -Tenant parameter but when I tested that it didn't have the desired effect.  That may be because my additional AAD tenants aren't associated with a subscription, unlike yours.  If that does work for you I'll edit my answer to include it

Comment: After logging in the way you showed above `Get-AzContext -ListAvailable` also lists the AAD context and its TenantID. Using `Set-AzContext -Tenant` does not work - even though I provide the TenantID of the AD of Subscription 2, it switches to Subscription 1 and its AD. **BUT:** Using `Select-AzContext [Name]` actually works. The only "problem" is that the Name is some fantasy name that Azure makes up using some subscription name, Tenant_ID and other things - every name looks different in its structure. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - feel free to include this in your answer!